# call of overloaded ‘abs(double&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11

we have following code in legacy and use this place hundread of place. I am compiling code with c++11 and got following error. I  can understand issue(saw couple of question on stackoverflow) as abs support int/long int in C++11.

Is there any way to avoid 100 place and replace abs with fabs. Can I update such a way if it can handle both version. any input.

> call of overloaded ‘abs(double&)’ is ambiguous

```
double abs(double d)
{
    return (d < 0 ? -d : d);
}
```

Comment: In C++ `std::abs()` function is defined _only_ in `std` namespace, so if you do NOT do `using namespace std;` anywhere, then there should be no such issue.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: @sklott No, standard libraries are allowed to additionally declare it in global namespace. The same is true for all contents of `<c...>` headers. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers

Comment: Maybe just remove the custom function and let `std::abs` kick in?

Comment: hmm did mistake my appology

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "each xxx.h header included in the C++ standard library places in the global namespace each name that the corresponding cxxx header would have placed in the std namespace." Obviously this only applicable when "xxx.h" headers is included and should be easily fixable by changing "xxx.h" headers to "cxxx" headers.

Comment: @sklott I'm referring to this part: *"`cxxx` headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the global namespace"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why redefine what is already defined?

You can find the function that you want in the header `<cmath>`.

Further reading on [c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cmath>
```

> add this header file and try to use abs() built-in function and see that work or not.